# PopOS detects MediaTek 0616 but has no wifi network device

Tags: wifi, drivers, pop-os

I just rebooted PopOS 22.04 LTS after updates. While lspci can detect

```
Network Controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:0616]
```

As a device, the OS does not recognize that as a Network Device and the setting screen refuse to believe that there exists wifi.

Any pointers would be appreciated. The wifi adapter is built into the motherboard, so should I attempt to remove CMOS and reset the board completely? Or is there some software setting that patching corrupted?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?

Comment: @AlfieDanger Turns out whatever the driver is doing it is not resetting the wifi device on power down. Remove battery and discharging the capacitors fixed the issue.